# Slick Autoplay doesn´t work

Tags: slick.js

I use a slick carousel on http://www.be-virtual.org/schnittchen (on the bottom of the page).

I use the following code to make the slides automatically:

```js
$('.center').slick({
  centerMode: true,
  centerPadding: '60px',
  autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 1000,
    dots: false,
    infinite: false,
    speed: 1000,
  responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 768,
      settings: {
        arrows: false,
        centerMode: true,
        centerPadding: '40px',
        slidesToShow: 3
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 480,
      settings: {
        arrows: false,
        centerMode: true,
        centerPadding: '40px',
        slidesToShow: 1
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

But that code doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling the slick carousel on a class named ".center", yet your carousel container doesn't have a class of center on it; it has a class of ".ca-container." Try to change one or the other in your code.